# Android Add Columns Dynamically To A ListView

Tags: android, listview, multiple-columns

I don't know if anyone needed this before, but I have to create a custom ListView which has to support this:

1. add columns dynamically (this means a list can have 1 columnn, 2, 3, ... ,50) when a button is pressed (an insert button)
2. when the user want to insert a column he has to choose if the column must be inserted before a specific column or after it.
   My question is, how can I achieve this? If I created the row of the list inside an xml file, how could I tell the column to be after a certain view or before?

I would appreciate any answer or suggestion. 
Thanks

Comment: do you mean rows or columns?

Comment: I mean columns. My list should look like a table, with multiple columns and rows, but the columns have to be added dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can create custom layout for row.
2. And add additional fields when you need additional rows.

Answer (score 0):

take LinerLayout as a horizontal,
on button click take index and add view according to index value,
consider possible values of index to avoid exception...

Comment: Should I create another view in a new xml file? I mean should I create an xml file containing views of how a column should look like?

Comment: yes u can....
just take Linear layout with horizonal,
and suppose u need 2 TextView, 1 Button or whatever as per ur requirement, add this into another xml,
add this xml's view in ur LinearLayout at run time with index values